# Determine MySQL port and IPTables restriction

Tags: mysql, linux

Linux CentOS 6 - IPTables

I would like to know what command line(s) I need to enter to determine what my MySQL port is, or rather what config file I could check.  I know it's typically 3306 but I'm not 100% sure this is the case.  It would just be nice to know how to check for future reference.

In addition, would it be possible to restrict that port to only accept my server's IP address?  Or I guess what I'm asking is if I can set up IPTables to only allow my server to talk to my MySQL database and deny all other incoming IPs, etc.

When performing `iptables -L` I see this :

`ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql`

which I'm assuming isn't ideal.  Forgive me if I'm too vague.

Edit: also forgive me if I'm asking too many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without checking config files, "netstat -pltn" is your friend. It Will tell you the process name and number of running tcp servers.

As for restrictions with iptables, after accepting valid connections you should drop the unwanted ones.

If you are connecting from the same machine, it's better to configure MySQL to bind to localhost.

Comment: The answer to http://serverfault.com/questions/201349/is-blocking-all-traffic-to-mysql-port-except-from-own-server-ip-a-good-securit is quite good for this question.